# estoy tratando de saber como es la manera correcta de estructurar un codigo para que me de la respuesta de las medidas de esos vectores

Tags: c++

**Encontrar las componentes rectangulares de un vector cuya magnitud es de 100N y
cuya dirección es de 35 grados con respecto a la horizontal.**

Comment: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pit%C3%A1goras

Comment: Esto no parece un problema de programación. Puedes resolver con trigonometría. Multiplica la magnitud del vector por el coseno y el seno del ángulo y tienes la componente horizontal y vertical respectivamente.